# Controlling tableview header view with autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, xib

I am loading a `UITableView` header from a xib. The header is displayed, however it is being stretched rather than being displayed as compact as possible.

Below is a screenshot from the view debugger:
[image: View debugger]

As you can see, the text field with "Bob's Pizza" has been stretched quite tall.

How can I get the view to layout to its minimum height?

Comment: Try using systemLayoutSizeFitting on table header view and set the same height to table header view frame size.

Comment: You should set the fixed height to the textField if is textField border style is UITextBorderStyleNone.